# How to add jQuery to an erb file using Foundation?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, erb

Thanks to some research and a little help from stack overflow I am very close to getting a desired effect in my rails app. I have an annoying bug and I don't understand what is causing this. Below I have a .each method that renders a task from my `_task.html.erb` file created by my rails app. I'm trying to get the different tasks to be color coded depending on their set priority levels but I just can't get to the last step. Thanks to craig.kaminsky, he saved me a lot of heartache from trying to use AJAX to initially do this. However, the jQuery isn't working but it should.

As shown below I have the script tags in place with the correct reference to `text/javascript`. Because of the asset pipeline, this jQuery should work and yet it doesn't. I don't know what gives.

```
<% @tasks.each do |task| %>
  <% if task.importance == "Low" %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $("td").addClass("green");
    </script>
  <% elsif task.importance == "Medium" %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $("td").addClass("orange");
    </script>
  <% elsif task.importance == "High" %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $("td").addClass("red");
    </script>
  <% end %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= task.name %></td>
    <td><%= task.description %></td>
    <td><%= task.start %></td>
    <td><%= task.finish %></td>
    <td><%=  task.importance  %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_task_path(task) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Remove', task_path(task), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are  
          you sure you would like to Delete? Did you complete the task?' } %></td>
 </tr>
<% end %>
```

Is their a dumb typo that I'm missing? Lastly, the error I am receiving is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

-----------------EDIT---------------------

This is my application.js file

```
   // This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will 
       include all the files listed below.

   // Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, 
      vendor/assets/javascripts,
   // or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a 
      relative path.
   // It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the 
      bottom of the compiled file.
   // Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets- 
      directives) for details
  // about supported directives.

  //= require jquery
  //= require jquery_ujs
  //= require foundation
  //= require_tree .



  $(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });
```

Comment: Can you show your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file?

Comment: Thanks for the reply zishe. I'll show it right now.

Comment: Seems file, don't know what's the problem.

Comment: Are you sure your jQuery is loaded first? I mean using firebug.

Comment: I don't know what firebug is but I'll look into it. The only other thing is that I get this error in the Inspect element console. Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined tasks:66
(anonymous function) I don't know what that refers o.

Comment: Get firefox, then install firebug extension. When installed you should see a bug icon in the right/top side of your window.

Comment: I installed firebug but still nothing. I just know that there is something wrong with $("td").addClass("red"). I just don't know how to fix it.

Comment: You are using jQuery selectors without document ready. Using firebug you must check the DOM and verify if your jQuery is loading first from head. Personally I would accept Subtletree's answer as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a rails helper method to insert the class server side instead of jquery.

E.g

**tasks_helper.rb**

```
  def get_importance_class(importance)
    case importance
      when 'low'
        "green"
      when 'medium'
        "orange"
      when 'high'
        "red"
      else
        ""
    end
  end
```

Then in your view you could do:

```
<% @tasks.each do |task| %>
  <% importance_class = get_importance_class(task.importance) %>

  <tr>
    <td class="<%= importance_class %>"><%= task.name %></td>
    <td class="<%= importance_class %>"><%= task.description %></td>
    <td class="<%= importance_class %>"><%= task.start %></td>
    <td class="<%= importance_class %>"><%= task.finish %></td>
    <td class="<%= importance_class %>"><%=  task.importance  %></td>
    <td class="<%= importance_class %>"><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_task_path(task) %></td>
    <td class="<%= importance_class %>"><%= link_to 'Remove', task_path(task), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are  
          you sure you would like to Delete? Did you complete the task?' } %></td>
 </tr>
<% end %>
```

If you are adding that class to each cell( `td` ) then you might want to apply it to the row instead

Comment: I'll try this out. Just one thing, where would I put this helper method?

Comment: When you generate a controller it creates a corresponding helper file in app/helpers/*controller_name*_helper.rb. So you might have a `tasks_helper.rb` file. It doesn't matter which helper file you put it in really, they just help keep things organised. You will have an `application_helper.rb` file that you could use.

Comment: Thanks for the help Subltetree, it still didn't work though I get a circular dependency error. I appreciate it though.

Comment: Hmm in that case i'm not sure what the problem is. The code pasted above works perfectly in my tests. What version of rails are you using? Try resetting the server and make sure you don't have 2 files named the same. Are you using `include` in any views/controllers/helpers?

Comment: @Subletree thanks a bunch. I don't know what happened but this time around I made it work. It must have been a typo on my part. Thanks for introducing me to helper modules and methods too. Much appreciated.